# How to debug eex template and @ variables?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this template

```
  <%= form_for @changeset, bid_path(@conn, :update, 1), [method: :put], fn f -> %>
    <% 
      require IEx
      IEx.pry
    %>
<%= if @changeset.action do %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How can I display @changeset in IEx console? When I'm trying to do this is blows an error:

```
pry(5)> @changeset
** (ArgumentError) cannot invoke @/1 outside module
    (elixir) lib/kernel.ex:3960: Kernel.assert_module_scope/3
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.@/1
             web/templates/bid/edit.html.eex:5: (file)
```

Comment: Does `assigns[:changeset]` work?

Comment: @Dogbert Yes! Thanks I couldn't find it anywhere :)

Comment: I was able to make this work in .heex templates: `<% assigns |> dbg() %>`. Once Pry pops up, I am able to do: `assigns[:name]`, and read the data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@` in `eex` templates in Phoenix is completely unrelated to `@` in Elixir/iex. In `eex` templates in Phoenix, [`@foo` is roughly equivalent to `Access.fetch!(assigns, :foo)`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/77da6b4dc99d6f5ec1acf71dc7601d0fd13b5e2b/lib/phoenix_html/engine.ex#L90-L113), while in Elixir/iex, they're used to define module attributes. So, in order to access `@changeset` in `iex`, you can can do:

```
Access.fetch!(assigns, :changeset)
```

or just the following if you're okay with getting `nil` for non-existent keys:

```
assigns[:changeset]
```

Comment: Can you please add an example in your answer for @ in a module in an elixir.

Comment: How do I use this in a template?  I don't think you have answered the question

Comment: I was able to make this work in .heex templates: `<% assigns |> dbg() %>`. Once Pry pops up, I am able to do: `assigns[:name]`, and read the data.

Comment: @MartinSommer That works great! That deserves to be its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `binding` (from `Kernel.binding/0`) to print all available variables and their values in your context