# How View attributes are created in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Could anyone explain me how the variable from the controller magically appears in the view as a module attribute?

For example, this `render/3` in the Controller:

```
defmodule MyApp.UserController do
  def show(conn, %{"id" => user_id}) do
    render conn, "show.html", user: Repo.get(User, user_id)
  end
```

creates an attribute `@user` I can use in the template like:

```
Hello, <%= @user.first_name %>
```

I understand that the template became function and it is located in the view, like `MyApp.UserView`. This means that `@user` is the attribute of `MyApp.UserView` module. But how?

Comment: I think the first two sentences of my answer here answers your question well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39391047/320615

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot @Dogbert, this is a right answer. I can imagine it is done to have templates rails-like look. Please post your answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could anyone explain me how the variable from the controller magically appears in the view as a module attribute?

They are not module attributes. EEx just uses the same syntax and makes their behavior pluggable by the user using an `EEx.Engine` behavior implementing module. [The default EEx Engine converts them to](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/e6971f966c486d212aec06e28a9ce6cce30a71ea/lib/eex/lib/eex/engine.ex#L60-L96) `EEx.Engine.fetch_assign!(var!(assigns), unquote(name))` while [Phoenix's Engine converts them to](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/77da6b4dc99d6f5ec1acf71dc7601d0fd13b5e2b/lib/phoenix_html/engine.ex#L90-L113) `Phoenix.HTML.Engine.fetch_assign(var!(assigns), unquote(name))` when the templates are compiled into functions.